# Amazon elastic container service - Kubernetes liveness/readiness checks equivalent for ECS

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, application-warmup

My task is to warm up an ASP.Net Core app that run inside Docker containers deployed on ECS. It seem that with Kubernetes, we can define a readiness check path that Kubernetes will first send request to and only start sending real traffic once that request is completed.

Do we have a equivalent feature on ECS?

A reference regarding this issue but can be solved in Kubernetes:
https://blog.markvincze.com/running-asp-net-core-in-auto-scaling-containers-warm-up/

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported yet.

There is an open ticket for that https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1670